# git bundle on unstaged local repo

Tags: git, git-stash

My local repo has some local modifications/changes (adding new mock files, commenting some third party dependency imports) to run my app. Those changes (8 files changes and 2 files newly added) are fixed ones I repeatedly do whenever I do a fresh checkout.

Now when I start using bundle to update my local repo,

1. Is it possible to pull/update my local repo (with unstaged changes) from the bundle? Should i undo all those local changes and only then can run update of the bundle?
2. Will stashing help me out? Meaning first: stash the branch , second: update from bundle my local repo, third: apply back the stash to the updated repo branch .....

Please help me out with ur ideas/suggestions

Answer (score 0):

`git stash` then `git pull` then `git stash apply` should work.

You will not be able to `pull` with unstaged changes. Or staged ones.

However, in the long run it may be worth thinking about why you keep needing to do this and finding a way to incorporate your changes so they work for everyone.

Comment: Local changes are needed to run my app local to my machine for my BAU prupose. Existing project has other project dependency which i think local to my system , i dont need those up. Hence doing those local changes.

Comment: Some form of config or different build configuration for each setup may help